# C open file using a function

Tags: c, function, file

I am pretty new to C and I am struggling to write to files form my C program. In this program I open files to read from as well as files to write to, so I thought I'll make a function that opens the file for me. This is what I did

```
FILE *open_file(char* filename, char* mode)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(filename, mode);
    if(!f)
    {
        perror(filename)
        exit(EXIT_FAILLURE);
    }
    return f;
}
```

And this is how I call the function:

```
FILE *infile = open_file(args.infile_name, "r");
FILE *rm_file = open_file(args.rm_file, "r");
FILE *ex_file = open_file(args.ex_file, "w");
```

Those function calls are spread throughout the program. first I had the mode "r" hardcoded in there because I only needed to read from files, but now I also want to write for a file, so I made a parameter for the modus in which the file should be opened. It worked fine before, but now it does nothing. I compiles fine, without any errors, warnings and/or notes. Also valgrind tells me that everything is fine. Any thoughts on this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to add the line where I returned f, I added it now. It was in my code already (ofcourse, you can't let a non void function return nothing).

EDIT: Better explanation of the "error": I am trying to read words from a file and store them in a tree like datastructure. This is working fine, I can look them up and all so no problems here. After adding words to the tree I print the amount of words found in the file and the amount of words added to the tree (I don't add words that are already there). Now I want to export the tree to a file so I need to open a file I can write to. Since I had hardcoded the open_file with the read-only modus, I added a parameter for the modus. But when I run the program now it gives no error (so the filepointer isn't NULL) but just says 0 words found in file and 0 words added. Also the file I print to stays empty. Hope this makes it a little clearer

Comment: **Always** enable the recommended compiler warnings. As a beginner make them errors.

Comment: UB which would have been diagnosed by any compiler if warnings were enabled. Close vote. Retracted downvote since the relevant information is there

Comment: @AnttiHaapala As OP likely doesn't know: UB stands for *undefined behaviour* which is when you do something you are not allowed to do. In this case, behaviour is undefined and everything can happen, including little dæmons flying out of your nose!

Comment: make sure also close files when done using them

Comment: Try to printf filename and mode inside of the function.  Maybe there is something wrong with your args struct.  How are you initializing the strings in args?  If you do it with just assignment in a function other than main the memory may get freed at the end of the function call.  Which is an issue.  Then again strings are often stored in a form of constant memory, unless you are initializing them like `char string[] = "hello";`

Comment: I close all my files, but not necessarily before I open a new one.

Comment: @Danagon You must more specifically describe what the problem is then and where

Comment: @chasep255 The arguments are passed along just fine. I declare the file pointer in my main function, call open_file from main and close them before the main ends.

Comment: @Giorgi Moniava I'm not sure. First I hardcoded the "r" modus in there because I only wanted to read files. When I made a parameter for this is stopped doing anything at all. It does not return an error, so the pointer is not NULL after fopen, but It's not able to get anything from it.

Comment: @Danagon Did you try checking errno? Where do you get error? "stopped doing anything at all." is not clear way to describe your problem

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava dont't get an error, I am trying to add words from a file to a tree like structure. I print the amount of words in the file and the amount of words added to the tree. It worked fine, but now I want to export the tree to a file, so I changed my open_file function. now it says it found 0 words and added 0 words.

Comment: @Danagon Post a new question with MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then. This way it is not clear what the issue is

Comment: Ok, now the undefined behaviour is gone, and I downvoted the question since there is no MCVE anymore.

Answer (score 6):

```
FILE *open_file(char* filename, char* mode)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(filename, mode);
    if(!f)
    {
        perror(filename)
        exit(EXIT_FAILLURE);
    }
}
```

Your function doesn't return anything. Simply add `return f;` at the end. Seems your wrapper is doing little work though, could have also put this code where you are using it directly, instead of having this function.

Comment: I do return f, I forgot to add it to the code snippet. Thanks for noticing

Comment: I don't think I do. I close the first file I open at the end of the program. Is it not possible to have multiple files open at the same time?

Comment: @Danagon Yes you can have multiple different files open at the same time; check also [errno](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/) if fopen fails to get a clue what is the problem with fopen

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava `perror` prints the error behind `errno` in clear text, surely it doesn't get unnoticed

Comment: @AnttiHaapala oops didn't see that.